# Weblogic Providers

Tags: authentication, weblogic, roles, jdeveloper

I have created a custom authentication provider that checks if a user exists in a datasource and allows it to login or not.

Now I also have to check the roles of that user, but I don't understand if the same provider can take care of Authentication and Role mapping or if I have to do another provider.

I had tried to created another provider, for the role mapping, but I can't find it, or not looking in the right place to configurate it, but my MBean type also doesn't any configs to be inserted.

Can anyone help me with this?
I tried to find examples of role mapping, with no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Oracle Guide: [How to Develop a Custom Role Mapping Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/DEVSP/rm.htm#DEVSP368%20How%20to%20Develop%20a%20Custom%20Role%20Mapping%20Provider)

The process is very similiar to creating an authentication Provider, the only difference are the interfaces you have to implement.

Now for my Implementation (I assume knowledge about MBean Provider Creation using the WebLogicMBeanMaker, since you already created an Authentication Provider):
You need 3 Files, a XML File with the configuration, the Provider and the Implementation of a Role.

The Config File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE MBeanType SYSTEM "commo.dtd">

<MBeanType
 Name          = "MYRoleMapper"
 DisplayName   = "MYRoleMapper"
 Package       = "MY.security"
 Extends       = "weblogic.management.security. authorization.RoleMapper"
 PersistPolicy = "OnUpdate"
>
 <MBeanAttribute
  Name          = "ProviderClassName"
  Type          = "java.lang.String"
  Writeable     = "false"
  Preprocessor  = "weblogic.management.configuration.LegalHelper.checkClassName(value)"
  Default       = "&quot;MY.security.MYRoleMapperProviderImpl&quot;"
 />

 <MBeanAttribute
  Name          = "Description"
  Type          = "java.lang.String"
  Writeable     = "false"
  Default       = "&quot;MY RM provider &quot;"
 />

 <MBeanAttribute
  Name          = "Version"
  Type          = "java.lang.String"
  Writeable     = "false"
  Default       = "&quot;1.2&quot;"
 />

</MBeanType>
```

The Actual Provider MYRoleMapperProviderImpl.java:

```
public class MYRoleMapperProviderImpl implements RoleProvider, RoleMapper {
    private String description;
    private static final Map<String, SecurityRole> NO_ROLES = Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<String, SecurityRole>(1));

    private final static String RESSOURCE_URL = "<url>";
    private final static String RESSOURCE_EJB = "<ejb>";

    private enum rollen {
        READER;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(ProviderMBean mbean, SecurityServices services) {
        description = mbean.getDescription() + "\n" + mbean.getVersion();
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    @Override
    public void shutdown() {

    }

    @Override
    public RoleMapper getRoleMapper() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, SecurityRole> getRoles(Subject subject, Resource resource, ContextHandler handler) {
        Map<String, SecurityRole> roles = new HashMap<String, SecurityRole>();
        Set<Principal> principals = subject.getPrincipals();
        for (Resource res = resource; res != null; res = res.getParentResource()) {
            getRoles(res, principals, roles);
        }
        if (roles.isEmpty()) {
            return NO_ROLES;
        }
        return roles;
    }

    private void getRoles(Resource resource, Set<Principal> principals, Map<String, SecurityRole> roles) {
        if (resource.getType() == RESSOURCE_URL || resource.getType() == RESSOURCE_EJB) {
                            roles.put(rollen.READER.toString(), new MYSecurityRoleImpl(rollen.READER.toString(), "READER Rolle"));          
            }
    }
}
```

And an absolute simple Role Implementation:

```
package MY.security;

import weblogic.security.service.SecurityRole;

public class MYSecurityRoleImpl implements SecurityRole {

    private String _roleName;
       private String _description;
       private int _hashCode;

       public MYSecurityRoleImpl(String roleName, String description)
       {
          _roleName = roleName;
          _description = description;
          _hashCode = roleName.hashCode() + 17;
       }

       public boolean equals(Object secRole)
       {
          if (secRole == null) 
          {
             return false;
          }

          if (this == secRole) 
          {
             return true;
          }

          if (!(secRole instanceof MYSecurityRoleImpl)) 
          {
             return false;
          }

          MYSecurityRoleImpl anotherSecRole = (MYSecurityRoleImpl)secRole;

          if (!_roleName.equals(anotherSecRole.getName())) 
          {
             return false;
          }

          return true;
       }

       public String toString () { return _roleName; }
       public int hashCode () { return _hashCode; }
       public String getName () { return _roleName; }
       public String getDescription () { return _description; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
As for the number of providers, can I do it in one? Authorization and Role Mapping together, or do I have to split them?

Comment: I am not sure, since I implemented only a RoleMappingProvider before. If you look at the example, there is a method in the AuthenticationProvider addGroupsForSubject(String userName). That might be worth a try

Comment: ok, and the role mapper provider jar will be in the mbeantypes in the server correct?
Is there a way that you can send me the role mapper code that you tested?

Comment: Yes, it also goes in the mbeantypes folder. And sure, I can show you the code. Just have to remove some company specific stuff from it before I can post it here ,)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply Slettal.
The role mapper provider should appear in the Role Mapping tab, inside Providers tab inside 'myrealm' correct?

Comment: I can't understand why the Run ant target doesn't return any errors and create the jar but the provider won't appear in the list to be chosen

Comment: Yes, you should be able to select it as a RoleProvider. Check the weblogic Logs when you start the server for errors, check the .xml File for any typos

Comment: I have opened the jar file that was generated and I saw that the java files inside the package I have created weren't there. I'm guessing that is why the reference of it won't appear on the list. When I run the build file I don't get any errors. Can't I use the build of the authentication provider in the roleMapper?

Comment: Yes, the build should be the same. It's just the call of the MBEAN Maker after all:
    <java classname="weblogic.management.commo.WebLogicMBeanMaker" fork="true" failonerror="true">
      <jvmarg line="-Dfiles=./build  -DMDFDIR=./build -DMJF=./build/MYRoleMapper.jar -DtargetNameSpace=${namespace} -DpreserveStubs=true -DcreateStubs=true"/>
    </java>

Comment: In case you did not see that, Oracle has a Database user security provider sample with a working build job at their homepage. That's the one I used:  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/indexes/samplecode/weblogic-sample-522121.html

Comment: Ok, I have successfully compile the provider and make it appear in the weblogic list for role mapper. But I have some functions to implement like removeRolesForComponent, getRoles, etc. Is here where i add the queries to my database? I can't find an example, even from the oracle pages

Comment: Yes, see my posted Code. The Provider has a Method getRoles. That one gets called by Weblogic for every access to any ressource (I restricted that to url and ejb requests). That's where you would add the query to the database.