# Deploying Custom RoleMapper to WebLogic

Tags: authentication, weblogic, roles

I am trying to deploy a Custom Role Mapper in WebLogic 10.3.5.0 - this is very similar to this question - [Weblogic Providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020810/weblogic-providers), but I cannot get the provider to appear in the poplist.

Config file:

```
<MBeanType Name="DatabaseRoleMapping" 
       DisplayName="DatabaseRoleMapping" 
       Package="com.bynx.weblogic.mbean.rolemapping"
       Extends="weblogic.management.security.authorization.RoleMapper"
       PersistPolicy = "OnUpdate"> 
<MBeanAttribute
 Name = "ProviderClassName"
 Type = "java.lang.String"
 Writeable = "false"
 Preprocessor  = "weblogic.management.configuration.LegalHelper.checkClassName(value)"
 Default = "&quot;com.bynx.weblogic.mbean.rolemapping.DatabaseRoleMappingProvider&quot;"
/>

<MBeanAttribute
 Name = "Description"
 Type = "java.lang.String"
 Writeable = "false"
 Default = "&quot;Provider that performs Role Mapping held in a database&quot;"
/>

<MBeanAttribute
 Name = "Version"
 Type = "java.lang.String"
 Writeable = "false"
 Default = "&quot;1.0&quot;"
/>
<!-- 
<MBeanAttribute
 Name = "DataSourceJNDI"
 Type = "java.lang.String"
 Default = "&quot;UserDataSource&quot;"
 Description = "DataSource JNDI name"
/> -->
</MBeanType>
```

Provider Imlementation:

```
package com.bynx.weblogic.mbean.rolemapping;

import weblogic.management.security.ProviderMBean;
import weblogic.security.spi.RoleMapper;
import weblogic.security.spi.RoleProvider;
import weblogic.security.spi.SecurityServices;

public class DatabaseRoleMappingProvider implements RoleProvider
{
    DatabaseRoleMapper mapper;
    private String description;

    @Override
    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(ProviderMBean provider, SecurityServices services)
    {
        //DatabaseRoleMappingProviderMBean mBean = (DatabaseRoleMappingProviderMBean)provider;
        //mapper = new DatabaseRoleMapper(mBean.getDataSourceJNDI());
        mapper = new DatabaseRoleMapper("UserDataSource");
        description = provider.getName() + " " + provider.getVersion();
    }

    @Override
    public void shutdown()
    {

    }


    @Override
    public RoleMapper getRoleMapper()
    {
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Build file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

  <project name="dbuser_authentication_provider" default="all" basedir=".">

  <!-- global properties -->
  <property environment="env"/>
  <property name="jdk"                 value="C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_26"/>
  <property name="lib"                 value="P:/Web_Dev/Projects/WebLogic_Home/wlserver_10.3/server/lib"/>
  <property name="mbeantypes"          value="${lib}/mbeantypes"/>
  <property name="sampleprovidersjar"  value="databaseRoleMapping.jar"/>
  <property name="sample_dir"          location="."/>
  <property name="src_dir"             value="${sample_dir}/src"/>
  <property name="provider_src_dir"    value="${src_dir}/com"/>
  <property name="build_dir"           value="${sample_dir}/build"/>
  <property name="class_dir"           value="${sample_dir}/classes"/>
  <property name="namespace"           value="http://www.bea.com/ns/90/weblogic/security/samples"/>

  <target name="all" depends="clean">

    <!-- Set up the build directories -->
    <mkdir dir="${build_dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${class_dir}"/>

    <!-- Only copy over the commo dtd and sample provider xml files for now -->
    <copy todir="${build_dir}" flatten="true">
      <fileset dir="${lib}">
        <include name="commo.dtd"/>
      </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${build_dir}" flatten="true">
      <fileset dir="${provider_src_dir}">
        <include name="**/*.xml"/>
        <include name="**/*.java"/>
      </fileset>
    </copy>

    <!-- Build the sample security providers' jar file -->
    <java classname="weblogic.management.commo.WebLogicMBeanMaker" fork="true" failonerror="true">
      <jvmarg line="-cp '${jdk}/lib/tools.jar';${lib}/weblogic.jar -Dfiles=${build_dir}  -DMDFDIR=${build_dir} -DMJF=${build_dir}/${sampleprovidersjar} -DtargetNameSpace=${namespace} -DpreserveStubs=true -DcreateStubs=true"/>
    </java>

  </target>

  <target name="clean">
    <delete quiet="true" dir="${build_dir}"/>
    <delete quiet="true" dir="${class_dir}"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

Everything compiles fine and there don't appear to be any missing class files in the generated jar, but putting the jar in the mbeantypes directory and restarting it doesn't appear in the list.  It will eventually look at a database, but I have stripped it down to the minimum to try and get it working.  Any suggestions - or where to look in the logs for any issues would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get this working, so thought I would share my solution in case anyone else stumbles upon this.

First the statement in the documentation:

> However, if you want WebLogic Server to look for MBean types in additional directories, use the -Dweblogic.alternateTypesDirectory= command-line flag when starting your server, where  is a comma-separated list of directory names. When you use this flag, WebLogic Server will always load MBean types from WL_HOME\server\lib\mbeantypes first, then will look in the additional directories and load all valid archives present in those directories (regardless of their extension).

Doesn't appear to be correct.  We are using the alternateTypesDirectory parameter and I could only get WebLogic to pickup my custom MBean if I put the jar in one of the directories in the command-line flag.

Secondly, if you have anything deployed that uses versioning (e.g. one or more of the optional deployable libraries), your custom provider must implement the weblogic.security.spi.VersionableApplicationProvider interface and have`Implements = "weblogic.management.security.ApplicationVersioner"` in the MBeanType element of the definition XML.